# Values not getting when inserting in php

Tags: php, sql, arrays, post

```
<label><input type="radio" name="rval<?php echo $qid; ?>[]" value="2" id="rval<?php echo $qid; ?>_1" style="cursor: pointer">2&emsp;</label>
```

I added the above code in my php. And called this value for inserting to sql like below.

```
<?php
$fqid  = mysql_real_escape_string($fqid);
$qrval = isset($_POST["rval$fqid"]);
?>
```

But I am not getting any values from radio button. `qid` & `fqid` is same. Any help would be appreciated.

Full Code:

```html
<?php
 $pid=$_GET["pid"];
 $user=$_SESSION["user"];
 $centre=$_SESSION["centre"];
 $credate=date('d-m-Y');
 
 if(isset($_POST["pf_submit"])){
$query = "insert into s_answer (qnid,pid,answer,centre) values ";
foreach($_POST["fqid"] as $i => $fqid) 
{ 
  // Get values from post.
 
 $fqid = mysql_real_escape_string($fqid);
 $anstype=$_POST["atype"];
 $qfrval=isset($_POST['frval']);
 $qtval=isset($_POST['tval']);
 
   
 $antype=$anstype[$i];
   $rval = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["rval$fqid"][$i]);
   $frval = mysql_real_escape_string($qfrval[$i]);
 $tval = mysql_real_escape_string($qtval[$i]);
 
 if($antype=='Linear'){ $ans=$rval;}
 else if($antype=='Radio'){ $ans=$frval;}
 else if($antype=='Text'){ $ans=$tval;}

  // Add to database
  $query = $query." ('$fqid','$pid','$rval','$centre') ,";
}
$query = substr($query,0,-1); //remove last char
$result = mysql_query($query);


$sug=isset($_POST["sug"]);
if($sug != ""){
 mysql_query("insert into suggestion (sug,pid,centre) values ('$sug','$pid','$centre') ");
}
 
if($result){
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
  window.alert('Feedback has been submitted successfully. Thank you for your valuable feedback!')
        window.location.href='home.php'
        </SCRIPT>");
 }
else
{
 
 $error=mysql_error(); 
 
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(\"$error\");</script>";
}
 }
 
 
 ?>
```

Form Code:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal bucket-form" action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <?php
         $qres=mysql_query("select * from s_question order by qid asc");
         $i=0;
         while($qrow=mysql_fetch_array($qres))
         {
          $i++;
          $qid=$qrow["qid"];
          $atype=$qrow["anstype"];
          
          
          ?>
          <div style="display: none"><input name="fqid[]" value="<?php echo $qid; ?>" ></div>
          <div style="display: none"><input name="atype[]" value="<?php echo $atype; ?>" ></div>
          <?php
          
          if($atype=="Linear")
          {
           $ansres=mysql_query("select * from q_answer where qid='$qid' and anstype='Linear'");
           $ansrow=mysql_fetch_array($ansres);
         ?>
                           <div class="form-group">
                                    <label><?php echo $qrow["qn"]; ?></label>
                                    
                             <p>
                                      <label><?php echo $ansrow["l1"]; ?>&emsp;
                                        <input type="radio" name="rval<?php echo $qid ?>[]" value="1" id="rval<?php echo $qid; ?>_0" style="cursor: pointer">
                                        1&emsp;</label>
                                      <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="rval<?php echo $qid ?>[]" value="2" id="rval<?php echo $qid; ?>_1" style="cursor: pointer">
                                        2&emsp;rval<?php echo $qid; ?></label>
                                      <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="rval<?php echo $qid ?>[]" value="3" id="rval<?php echo $qid; ?>_2" style="cursor: pointer">
                                        3&emsp;</label>
                                      <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="rval<?php echo $qid ?>[]" value="4" id="rval<?php echo $qid; ?>_3" style="cursor: pointer">
                                        4&emsp;</label>
                                      <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="rval<?php echo $qid ?>[]" value="5" id="rval<?php echo $qid; ?>_4" style="cursor: pointer">
                                        5&emsp;</label>
                                      <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="rval<?php echo $qid ?>[]" value="6" id="rval<?php echo $qid; ?>_5" style="cursor: pointer">
                                        6&emsp;</label>
                                      <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="rval<?php echo $qid ?>[]" value="7" id="rval<?php echo $qid; ?>_6" style="cursor: pointer">
                                        7&emsp;</label>
                                      <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="rval<?php echo $qid ?>[]" value="8" id="rval<?php echo $qid; ?>_7" style="cursor: pointer">
                                        8&emsp;</label>
                                      <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="rval<?php echo $qid ?>[]" value="9" id="rval<?php echo $qid; ?>_8" style="cursor: pointer">
                                        9&emsp;<?php echo $ansrow["l2"]; ?></label>
                             </p>

                                </div>
          
                             
                             <?php } } ?> 
                             
                           
                            <div class="form-group">
                                                    <button type="submit" name="pf_submit" class="btn btn-danger">Next</button>
                                            </div>
                                            </form>
```

var_dump result:
Array ( [fqid] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 ) [atype] => Array ( [0] => Linear [1] => Linear ) [rval1] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) [rval3] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) [sug] => [pf_submit] => )

Comment: Where is the value of variable $fqid coming from? If $fqid is not set to the correct value, then isset($_POST["rval$fqid"]) will return false.

Comment: I didnt mentioned that line here. Already defined as $_POST["qid"] above this line in my php. And i am also getting the value to my sql tablr also.

Comment: I think I need to see more code to work out what's going on here. What is the output of `var_dump($_POST)`?